# VIM really slow with long yaml

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2

I have a 624 line Yaml file that is completely unusable in vim.

Here's is my config: https://github.com/brandonhilkert/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc

If I run "syntax off" if works fine but obviously doesn't highlight. Is there some way to improve this?

None of the lines are that long: https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/00391q2h0T0z0K0o3A1y/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-18%20at%2011.17.48%20AM.png?v=6532af86

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It has been [reported](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=719510) that the vanilla `YAML` syntax file is buggy, cause instability in Vim 7.4.

You can try this [vim-yaml](https://github.com/stephpy/vim-yaml) file.

Comment: Idk, it _is_ faster, but . . . not by much. yml files still lag for me.

Comment: Huge improvement for me with vim on elementaryOS.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone (like me) wondering how to install it:
Simply copy the entire `after` dir from the linked repo into your `$HOME/.vim` dir.

Comment: To add to @Alderath 's comment, you can download the `after` directory by using this: https://download-directory.github.io/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fstephpy%2Fvim-yaml%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2Fafter